# Fine Grained Permission Report

Tags: permissions

We have a few document libraries that have fine grained permissions.  Is there a report, tool, app that can show who has access to documents?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to elaborate your question a little bit more. Which version of SharePoint are you using? Is it SharePoint Server Online? is it On-Premises?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this PowerShell, it will iterate through all items in the specified list, and output the permissions for that item

```
$webURL = http://YOURINTRANETADDRESS;
$web = Get-SPWeb $webURL;
$list = $web.Lists["LIST NAME"];
foreach ($item in $list) {
    $item.Permissions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this powershell code, that writes a .CSV file:

```
set-variable -option constant -name out -value "e:\deploy\doclibpermissions.csv"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load(“Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c”) | out-null
$site = get-spsite http://yoursite
$web = $site.RootWeb 
write-host $web.Title
$list = $web.Lists["YourList"] 
foreach ($doc in $list.items) 
{
            "-------------------------------------------------------------------------" | Out-File $out -Append                                 
            $roleAssignments = $doc.RoleAssignments
            if ($roleAssignments.Count -gt 0) {
                foreach ($role in $roleAssignments) {         
                    write-host $role.Member -foregroundcolor "yellow"
                    $doc["Title"] + ","  + $role.Member  | Out-File $out -Append            
                }
            }
            else {
                    $doc["Title"] + ", permissions inherited"  | Out-File $out -Append            
            }           
            "-------------------------------------------------------------------------" | Out-File $out -Append                 
}
$web.Dispose();
$site.Dispose();
```